# Understanding Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I need some help to have a better understanding of Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS).

From what I understood (from official and unofficial documentaion), AKS provides everything I need to work with a K8s cluster, that is to say all nodes I need for my deployments. All these nodes are VMs in their (Microsoft) Clou and are created  on each deployment. Is that correct ?

Is it possible to add my personnal nodes in the cluster ?

Actually, I have some RPi that I want to use as nodes in a K8s cluster. I want to use K8s to manage the deployments of some docker application on my Raspberry Pis. I would like to know if it's possible to do that with AKS.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, AKS is just a managed kubernetes service, you cannot add your own nodes to it, since you dont control masters. you can look at [AKS-engine](https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine). that is an easy way to create a kubernetes cluster that you will manage and can do anything with it.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the confirmation, that's what I thought. I will have a look to AKS-engine